# SD Card not working after partition

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, internal-storage, external-sd, samsung-galaxy-s-5, partitions

I was falling short of memory on my Samsung Galaxy S5 16 GB running on Android Marshmallow 6.0.1 rooted and TWRP recovery so I bought a new 32 GB Micro SD Card and made partition with this Command a month ago :-

```
adb shell
sm partition disk:179,64 mixed 50
```

and the partition completed successfully. Now from past few days it is not working. when I open settings it says Checking. when I checked `adb shell` `sm list-volumes` it outputs this

```
shell@klte:/ $ sm list-volumes
private:179,67 checking 9d457504-6aea-4eaf-8514-3d25c9ed5846
private mounted null
public:179,65 HiddenMount D27B-3E68
emulated mounted null
privatemode unmounted null
```

I dont know what went wrong. please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

It was a mistake to do partitioning by yourself. Android don't very like third-party partitioning tools.

I recommend you to format SD-card via standard Android menu. If it fails then use PC card-reader or even specialized software recovery tools.

Comment: The Partition was successful and also worked for a month or so but now I dont have any idea whats gone wrong

Answer (score -1):

Since your  on android m you can go to setting amd set the sd card as internal ternal storage if that helps you any

Comment: And how will it help?